# jQuery toggle a box inside a box

Tags: javascript, jquery

Trying to build a guestbook with some jQuery features..

Now when im clicking at the "Post"box it appears a new box with the name "MenuBox" (This box is always hidden) i got the toggle part to work ALMOST.

The meaning of the MenuBox, is that it should show over the PostBox with a delete button so they can delete the post.

But now when i try to toggle it, it toggles all the boxes, is there a possible way of like making  `$("$(this) .MenuBox").click(`

Anyone got any clue?

Sorry if the explanation is bad..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provided that `.MenuBox` is a child of `$(this)`:

```
$(this).find('.MenuBox').click(...);
```